# Radio button checked not working inside a table

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Excellent</th>
            <th>Satisfactory</th>
            <th>Unsatisfactory</th>
            <th>Poor</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php 
                $empty = false;
                $x = 1 ;
                while($x<=4)
                {
                    if($Comments['Preparation']==$x)
                    {
                        $empty = true;
                    }
                    $x++;
                }
            ?>
            <td><b>Preparation</b>- Applicant has prepared his/her himself for the interview and the necessary documents.</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="4" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='4') {echo "checked='checked'";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled='disabled'";}?>></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="3" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='3') {echo "checked='checked'";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled='disabled'";}?>></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="2" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='2') {echo "checked='checked'";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled='disabled'";}?>></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="1" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='1') {echo "checked='checked'";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled='disabled'";}?>></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

I am trying to pre-select a radio button inside a table because I want to display it. The `if` statements signify whether I will echo "checked". I have been using it outside the table and it works fine. 
Is checked for radio button possible to use in a table?

What's the problem?

Comment: 'not working' is ot a good description. Whats actually happening? How does this differ from your expected outcome

Comment: My expected outcome is when I echo checked the radio button will be checked. What's happening is that the other radio button get disabled but the radio button that is supposed to selected is not selected

Comment: Instead of `echo "Checked=''";` it should just be `echo "checked";` and not as `checked="checked"`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `{echo "Checked=''";} else if($empty) {echo "Disabled=''";}`

it should just be 
`{echo "checked";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled";}`

`checked=checked` etc. isn't how forms handle how a radio is checked, it's just

```
<input type="radio" value="radio_value" checked name="radio_name">
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

and not

```
<input type="radio" value="radio_value" checked=checked name="radio_name">
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is what you are doing right now.

same thing for `disabled`

```
<input type="radio" value="radio_value" disabled name="radio_name">
                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can setup pre-defined variables:

```
$disabled = 'disabled';

$checked = 'checked';
```

then do it dynamically

`{echo $checked;} else if($empty) {echo $disabled;}`

---

As per your edit:

`{echo "checked='checked'";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled='disabled'";}`

change it to

`{echo "checked";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled";}`

or as outlined above and use variables which can be changed anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing `"checked=''"` and `"disabled=''"`, change it to `"checked='checked'"` and `"disabled='disabled'"`.  Also, what is `$empty`?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="3" checked="checked"> I have done it and still in my browser the radio button is not checked. $empty is a boolean if the radio button will be disabled

Comment: Could you post more of the code so I can see what's happening?  Adding checked="checked" should definitely pre-select a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='4') {echo "checked='checked'";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="4" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='4') {echo "checked";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled";}?>></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="3" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='3') {echo "checked";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled";}?>></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="2" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='2') {echo "checked";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled";}?>></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Preparation" value="1" <?php if($Comments['Preparation']=='1') {echo "checked";} else if($empty) {echo "disabled";}?>></td>
```

Thank you guys for helping me. I have solved the problem.

Comment: That's not how things are done on Stack. [`Read my comment to you`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162843/radio-button-checked-not-working-inside-a-table#comment41017312_26163343) in my answer.